# change VS Code Insider terminal from zsh to bash

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, zsh

I have updated my macOS to Catalina and the default terminal has changed to zsh in the VS Code Insider there, I need to change the terminal from zsh to bash.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **`Terminal: Select Default Profile`** command or the GUI [dropdown](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-profiles):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In settings, under Features->Terminal, you can specify the name or path to your shell.

Comment: Sorry did not get the options. could you please provide a gif?

Answer (score 0):

Change user's login shell:

```
  chsh -s path/to/shell_binary username
```